# Sidebar move after user scrolls down x amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's get straight to it: When the user scrolls x amount, I want the sidebar to begin to move.. Now, once the sidebar reaches its' end, I want it to stay fixed and scroll to the footer. Here's what I got.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajp44/

Here's my Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
// Cache selectors for faster performance.
var $window = $(window),
    $sidebar = $('#anchor'),
    $sidebarAnchor = $('#right');

// Run this on scroll events.
$window.scroll(function() {
    var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
    var div_top = $sidebarAnchor.offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
     // Make the div sticky.
     $sidebar.addClass('stick');
     $sidebarAnchor.height($sidebar.height());
    }
    else {
        // Unstick the div.
        $sidebar.removeClass('stick');
        $sidebarAnchor.height(0);
    }
});
});
```

For some reason JSfiddle isn't displaying what the Javascript is doing, but if you run it on your PC you can see. Whenever the user scrolls passed the ending of the sidebar, the sidebar doesn't scroll down with them like it is suppose to, instead, it jumps of to the right side of the page...

So my question is this: how do I stop the sidebar from jumping to the side of the page, and keep it within the restraints of the parent DIV?

Cheers!

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your jsfiddle. When trying to solve javascript issues the first place to start is to check for errors in the console.

Comment: Check the answer with updated fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `right : 0` in your `stick` class. In fixed elements, the position attributes are relative to the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning

Comment: I tried to get rid of right: 0;, but if you do, then the sidebar scrunches into about half its' size and pushes right up to the left side of the sidebar container.. Any fix for that? Btw--I fixed the Jsfiddle so you can take a look

Comment: @PixelReaper you might need to assign your sidebar and the parent container a pixel width.

Comment: Now, how can I stop it before it falls out of the bottom? @ixe